# Background boxes of elements in forms are visible and annoying

Tags: javascript, css, html

Trying to create forms for my website.
When tested, It looks fine in opera.

But when checked in chrome or mozilla browsers, I observe that I see background grey bordered boxes for each element in the form. When hover or focused I can see grey color filled the box. I can understand that it is to distinguish with other elements when focussed.

I have captured the outputs, you will understand when you see that.

I thought it is outline and tried to remove it with none, but it's not working.

```
<div class="emply-resume-list row mb-1" id="head1" style="display:block;">
<div class="col-md-12 emply-info">
    <div class="emply-resume-info-sams">
        <form role="form" action="/resumehead" method="post">
            <h4>Resume Headline</h4>
            <label>Resume Headline is the first point of contact with Recruiters</label>
            <textarea id="ta1" class="form-control" name="headline" style="height:120px; width:100%; resize:none;" onkeyup="countChars(this,'lab1',250);"></textarea>
            <label id="lab1" style="float:left">250 Character(s) Left</label>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  style="float:right;">Save</button>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Chrome Image :
[image: Chrome Image]
Opera Image :
[image: Opera Image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
#ta1{
    border: none;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    resize: none;
    background:none;
}
```

To your css

Comment: when I tried with this script, textarea box is not visible to enter data.

Comment: Sorry, did you want the text area to be visible? What part do you want to have showing?

Comment: Yeah you are correct, when we said border none, text area is visible, but I could not able to identify... I tried with off and on of border... then I got it...

But this doesn't solve my problem as attached in the post....

And also one more point to note down is we can't recreate this issue in jsfiddle...

Comment: Oh, ok, I see now. My screen brightness is at max, so I cant see the grey box unless I look at it at a steep angle. I can see the problem now. Give me a min.

Comment: Ok. This probably isn't the answer you want, but I copied your code into a local file and ran it in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Edge, and I cannot see the grey shaded area no matter how I look at it. You can change the color of the area by adding properties to your `form` tag (I tested with red and you can see the whole area). Try setting `form{background: none;}` if you want to control it manually. You could also use `white`. If none of that works, try clearing the cache of the browser you're viewing it with.

Comment: Yeah its really strange... Is that me I am getting this error or not... I will try to check in a different machine as I am trying in my local host.

Please check this image https://imgur.com/a/pyHNEq4 , 

form{
    background: red;
}

for focus and hover, used background-color: blue;

If you see the image, you can make out like the strange boxes I can see is out of CSS Box....

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/7xvy27U

Please check this image for display: block in Div, I am getting this green color; so I have used background-color: none and next outline: none and next outline-style: none; 

But nothing solved...

Comment: Yeah. I think I can see them... there are 6 (full) blocks like that in the image you posted, correct ?

Comment: Yes, 6 blocks in chrome and firefox....  But I can see only one block in opera...which is fine with me...  Can you please help me out in this, as its first I see as browser compatibility and I am not expecting solution straight away.. If its there ok... but at least how to solve at... 

Is there any option in css like when it is display block mode with some properties... then I think we can go ahead looking at it...

What do you say?

Comment: I'll do what I can... unfortunately I cannot reproduce the problem on my system with only the code you have provided. Is there more you can post? Maybe the CSS as well? It looks like something in the background that has an outline, but I cannot see it (even in dev tools).

Comment: Yeah finally... I tried it... dont know actual reasoning but it worked... 

I changed display:block to display: inline-block; It worked...

Then I checked that the width of div with block mode is more wider than inline-block, so I adjusted with width:100% and it worked fine.

You can check in https://imgur.com/a/bEWfwHB .

@Christopher thanks for your valuable time. Finally I solved and we can close this. Thanks once again.

Comment: No problem. Glad you found it. It's still a mystery why it happened, but at least it's not a problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed your first `div` in the ending. Please do this and check again.

Comment: Yeah its already there, I dont know I cant see in code... 

When I tried to edit the post to insert ending div, its already there, but dont know the reason its not visible in final submitted post.

But whatever, its already in code of testing.